# How to narrow down types for TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Error | TypeWithData'?

Tags: typescript

I have an arrow function:

```
const getCsrfToken = async () => {
  const csrfTokenResponse = await axios.get<any, AxiosResponse<CSRFToken>>(csrfUrl);
  if (csrfTokenResponse?.data) {
    return csrfTokenResponse.data;
  }
  return Error('Failed to fetch CSRF token.');
};
```

TypeScript gives this warning:

```
TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Error | CSRFToken'.
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Error'.
```

If axios returns a response, it will be of type `CSRFToken`, which definitely has a `data` property.

So, I thought using the `?` in `csrfTokenResponse?.data` would be sufficient to guarantee that axios returned `CSRFToken` and not `Error`, but TypeScript is still giving me this message.

How can I fix the TypeScript warning?

TypeScript 4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple ways you can go through fixing this error.

### casting

you can cast the return value if you're sure the return value is defined.

```
(csrfTokenResponse as CSRFToken).data
```

### type check before accessing

you can use the following utility type to assert if the returned value is an error

```
const isError = (err: unknown): err is Error => err instanceof Error;
```

### throw error instead of returning it.

you can keep a consistent return type by using `throw Error` instead of returning it.

### A better return format

the following return format is inspired by how *go* handles return values.

```
const getCsrfToken = async () => {
  const csrfTokenResponse = await axios.get<any, AxiosResponse<CSRFToken>>(csrfUrl);
  if (csrfTokenResponse?.data) {
    return [data, null] as const;
  }
  return [null, Error('Failed to fetch CSRF token.')] ;
};
```

and use it like this

```
const [data, error] = await csrfTokenResponse()
```